# Error when tring to run discord bot "node_sqlite3.node is not a valid Win32 application."

Tags: node.js, sqlite

**What happened?**

After reinstalling all of my packages, I tried running my discord bot but it gave me this error instead:

```
$ node Mei.js
module.js:681
  return process.dlopen(module, path._makeLong(filename));
                 ^

Error: \\?\C:\Users\RAP\Desktop\bots\mei-discord\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v57-win32-x64\node_sqlite3.node is not a valid Win32 application.
\\?\C:\Users\RAP\Desktop\bots\mei-discord\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v57-win32-x64\node_sqlite3.node
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:681:18)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\RAP\Desktop\bots\mei-discord\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\sqlite3.js:4:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
```

**Attempts to solve it**

I reinstalled my packages and things are still in the same way. Tried deleting sqlite3 and reinstalled, still the same results.

So how can I fix this error, it never happened to me before, probably might reinstall node and build tools to make things fresh again.

**More info**

OS: Windows 10 64-bit

Node version: v8.11.1